# Why does bitcoind (0.7.2) give an error when trying to issue getrawtransaction over RPC?

Tags: bitcoind

I am writing an web application using Python/Flask. I am using

http://laanwj.github.com/bitcoin-python/doc/

to connect to my bitcoind 0.7.2 server as follows:

```
conn = bitcoinrpc.connect_to_local()
accounts = conn.listaccounts(0)
```

This is all working well. However, when I attempt to use some of the newer raw transaction calls, I get an error. For example,

```
raw_transaction = conn.getrawtransaction(txid)
```

results in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'BitcoinConnection' object has no attribute 'getrawtransaction'
```

It seems (though I am not sure) that the methods that don't work for me are those that are listed here:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions

Thanks to anyone who can help on this.

Comment: While cdecker technically answers the question posed, I found that the best solution around the problem is to use the following package to connect with bitcoind:

https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular API client library does not yet implement all calls that are exposed by `bitcoind`. See the [API documentation](http://laanwj.github.com/bitcoin-python/doc/bitcoinrpc.connection.html) for a list of calls that are implemented.

The problem is that your Bitcoin client knows about `getrawtransaction` but the python library you're using to connect to it does not know what to do with it yet.

Answer (score 1):

While cdecker technically answers the question posed, I found that the best solution around the problem is to use the following package to connect with `bitcoind`:

https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc

Comment: If you're just looking for a JSON-RPC client lib in python then https://github.com/joshmarshall/jsonrpclib might be your thing.